# Can't get ubuntu server 20.04 installed on a intel 11700 hp pavilion gaming desktop tg01-2xxx

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, uefi, hp, intel

As stated, I have a hp pavilion gaming desktop tg01-2xxx of which Id like to install Ubuntu server on.
I have tried multiple times and multiple ways but nothing sticks. its failing differently every time. Mostly its just a blank screen, other times i get to the GRUB and press install, and Sometimes I get to name it before it crashes. This isn't my first install of Ubuntu server I as have got it to work on a apple mini 2012.

Anything helps!

What i have tried:
Ubuntu server 20.04,
Ubuntu server 23.10,
Ubuntu desktop 22.04,
Ubuntu desktop 23.10,

When I try to boot Ubuntu Desktop from the usb and all I get is a black screen, with both Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 and 23.10.

Secure boot disabled,
Virtualization technology disabled,
Hyper-threading disabled,
Sata set to AHCI,
Network boot disabled,

Specs:
Intel 11700,
256 M.2,
16 Gb ram,
hp proprietary MB,
and Ethernet internet connection tho MB

Comment: Ubuntu server does not have a GUI. Please describe your issue in detail. After reading your post, I didn't understand what is not working. If you are planning to use a GUI, use Ubuntu Desktop instead. It is simpler.

Comment: Sorry, i mean GRUB not GUi, and Ubuntu Desktop wont install either. as in, try to boot from the usb and all i get is a black screen, with Ubuntu Desktop  22.04 and 23.10.

Comment: Will the USB stick boot in Qemu (or another virtual machine)? Or even on another computer?

Comment: yes, i caved and used an older computer, and the install went smooth for Ubuntu server 20.04. Its now running pterodactyl. so my guess it had something to do with the UEFi bios of the Hp MB.

Comment: Try Ubuntu Server 22.04, since this is the latest stable release. And update the installer before you proceed.